# Trouble with pfgkeys and CircuiTikz (with dipchips)

Tags: errors, circuitikz, pgfkeys

I have trouble printing ICs with CircuiTikz. Most parts work fine but I can't set `\ctikzset` options as well as dipchips.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

---

**MWE** (copy-paste 1st example, p. 91 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/circuitikz/doc/circuitikzmanual.pdf))

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/thickness=4}
    \ctikzset{multipoles/external pins thickness=2}
    \draw (0,0) node[dipchip,
        num pins=12,
        hide numbers,
        external pins width=0.3,
        external pad fraction=4 ](C){IC1};
    \draw (C.pin 1) -- ++(-0.5,0) to[R]
    ++(0,-3) node[ground]{};
    \node [right, font=\tiny]
    at (C.bpin 1) {RST};
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

> Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/dipchip' and I am
> going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
>
> Package pgfkeys Error:
> I do not know the key '/tikz/circuitikz/multipoles/thickness', to
> which you passed '4', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you
> misspelled it.
>
> [...]
>
> Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `pin' (in 'pin 1').
>
> [...]

Comment: You are looking at an old manual. If I copy the example just before section **3.25 Seven segment displays** in the most recent manual there is no error.

Comment: I copied from the most recent version 0.9.4 (2019/08/30). Your cited example does not compile either on my computer.

Comment: Do you have the newest version installed on your computer?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat The one that comes with [texlive 2019](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/any/texlive-latexextra/).

Answer (score 2):

Distributions are free to install the version they want... if you need newer versions, it's better either

1. install locally the packages you want at the bleeding edge of development, see for example  [Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te)

or

2. [install a pure TeX-Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)  (but notice that this is often not trivial to mix with your distribution, see for example [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Schrödinger'scat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/194703/schr%c3%b6dingers-cat) for the hint! It turns out that the current (2019) texlive distribution on Arch packages the ancient version 0.8.3 from [May 28, 2017](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/commit/03b94a31f3618cf0b47c39d140e865dcaff38f07).

Both examples compile using the recent version [0.9.3](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/master/tex/circuitikz-0.9.3.sty) from Github via `\usepackage{circuitikz-0.9.3}`.